# How to turn a order items into a column list of products

Tags: sql, select, pivot-table

I am trying to get an a list of products for an order listed as columns. I tried a pivot table but i dont want the column names to be that of the product but static names like product 1, product 2 and then the row will have the product sku and quantity. All the same products should go in the same column. like all sku1 in product1 column etc

example. order and orderitems table.
then output like

**header:**

orderid,product1, quantity1,product2 quantity2,product3,quantity3

**rows:**

1 , sku1,3, sku2,4, sku3,5

2 , sku1,2, sku2,5, sku3,1

i have created a sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d993a/4/0 with example of structure and select.

My last thought is a table variable with all revant columns and then insert into but still i cant see that it is the best option.

thanks in advance.....

Comment: show the table structures

Comment: they are in the sql fiddle. that's why i added the link. I thought it would make it far easier for everyone..?

Comment: I tried something on your data but i could only get what i posted in answer need more how quantity 1, quantity 2 ... value looks

Answer (score 0):

```
select  b.quantity, 
CASE WHEN b.productname='product 1' THEN b.sku END 'product1',
CASE WHEN b.productname='product 2' THEN b.sku END 'product2',
CASE WHEN b.productname='product 3' THEN b.sku END 'product3',
CASE WHEN b.productname='product 4' THEN b.sku END 'product4',
CASE WHEN b.productname='product 5' THEN b.sku END 'product5',
CASE WHEN b.productname='product 6' THEN b.sku END 'product6' 
from order1 a join orderitems b on (a.orderid=b.orderid) where a.orderid=
b.orderid ;
```

Output:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| quantity | product1 | product2 | product3 | product4 | product5 | product6 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|        2 | sku1     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
|        4 | NULL     | sku2     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
|        5 | NULL     | NULL     | sku3     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
|        2 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | sku4     | NULL     | NULL     |
|        1 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | sku5     | NULL     |
|        2 | sku1     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
|        4 | NULL     | sku2     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
|        5 | NULL     | NULL     | sku3     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
|        2 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | sku4     | NULL     | NULL     |
|        1 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | sku5     | NULL     |
|        1 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | sku6     |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: thanks for your help. its not right though as we never know the sku's etc. I have done now with table variables and loops. thanks all